# Qt4 QGraphicsView: How-to set QPen on float position

Tags: qt4, qgraphicsview

I've a QGraphicsView with an image and a custom cursor. The cursor is made out of two QPen-DotLines. A x-axis dotLine and a y-axis dotLine. The cross of the two lines is the mouse-cursor position. The problem, when I zoom in, the cross is not more under the mouse-cursor position. For example, when the values of the mouse-cursor are x = 1.4235 ans y = 2.7732
then the dotLines are set on the position x = 1 and y = 2. But I want to have the dotLines on the float position (x = 1.4235 ans y = 2.7732). How can I do that.

Mouse position I get with

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
    ...
    ... self.grview.mapToScene(event.pos())
    ...
```

and the dotLines I set with setPos(). 
I think setPos() converts float to int. But I don't know how to work around. Hope someone of you has an helpful idea.

Comment: When you say "custom cursor" are you actually modifying the system mouse pointer or doing some drawing in the scene or view under the actual mouse pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The guy who implemented some of the code before used "drawEllipse ( int x, int y, int width, int height )" and this converts float to int. So the only thing I had to do is to replace it with "drawEllipse ( const QPointF & center, qreal rx, qreal ry )". 
Sorry for the trouble and thank you.